# Newly created communication site not in audit log in Microsoft graph api directory Audits

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

According to [Microsoft graph API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), `auditLogs/directoryAudits` returns all events, but I just created a communication SharePoint site and it is not in the logs, what way can I get the newly created communication site?

Comment: it returns events for Entra (Active Directory) but SharePoint is another part of M365 ecosystem. Do you want to only periodically check newly created sites during some period?

Comment: @user2250152 Yes

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check newly created SharePoint sites, you have two options.

Use [/sites/getAllSites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-getallsites?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint and filter sites by `createdDateTime`. This endpoint supports only application permissions.

```
GET /v1.0/sites/getAllSites?$filter=createdDateTime ge 2024-01-01
GET /v1.0/sites/getAllSites?$filter=createdDateTime ge 2024-01-01 and createdDateTime lt 2024-02-01
```

Use [Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files#example-3-search-sites) to search for filtered sites

```
POST /v1.0/search/query
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "site"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "created>=2024-01-01 AND created<=2023-01-31"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```